# Inverse ARP lookup

Tags: mac-address, lookup

How can I do an inverse ARP lookup in Windows and/or Linux? Say that I have the MAC address of wireless access point which is up and running in the network, but I forgot it's IP address?

Comment: I know I'd get flamed with this if I put it as an answer: http://www.experts-exchange.com/Networking/Q_20279274.html

Comment: @Jeffrey - Just mark it as a community wiki - And if the referrer is not google the link is useless anyway.

Comment: You're right - that site really is the devil.

Comment: I believe the term is 'reverse arp', rather than inverse, you might have more luck searching with this.

Comment: I thought so too, but reverse arp is something else. It's asking the network what your own IP is (replaced by DHCP)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to ping the broadcast address (ping -b [broadcast address) on your subnet (often .255), and then dump your arp table (arp -a on Linux), and you should find the MAC of the machine, along with its IP.

Comment: Why the -b? On osx -b specifies an interface to bind to

Comment: @mist `-b` is required on Linux to ping broadcast, but not on OSX

Comment: Broadcast pings don't always work. I offer another solution in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Also you can use [nmap](http://nmap.org/) this is utility for network discovery, in Ubuntu you can simply install it from command line: `apt-get install nmap` 
For ping scan network use: `nmap -sP xx.xx.xx.xx/yy` as a result you find all hosts in network. You can use other [scan technics](http://nmap.org/book/man-host-discovery.html) (if host not respond to ICMP ping) for scanning the network.

Answer (score 3):

[arping2](http://www.habets.pp.se/synscan/programs.php?prog=arping) has an example `arping-scan-net.sh` which finds the IP address of a given mac address **in a given network subnet**. It works by scanning each ip address, so It works when broadcast pings are discarded (a very common situation)

Comment: The method provided in [`arping-scan-net.sh`](https://github.com/ThomasHabets/arping/blob/arping-2.x/extra/arping-scan-net.sh#L49) loops through IP addresses and invokes `arping -A -q -c 1 -T 192.168.0.$i $TARGET_MAC` which is timewise equivalent to pinging the given IP address. Is there any way to resolve IP address from given MAC with one utility invocation?

Answer (score 3):

Pinging the broadcast address only works for those things that respond to a broadcast ping, and not everything does. Another approach is to ping every address in the subnet, then review the ARP table.

In Windows, you can do this with:

```
for /l %i in (1,1,254) do ping -n 1 -w 50 192.168.0.%i
```

Basically, you are running ping in a 'for' loop. The arguments are thus:

- /l -- causes 'for' to loop
- %i -- incrementing variable
- (start, increment, end) -- the start, increment, and ending values
- -n -- number of packets to send
- -w -- time in milliseconds to wait for a reply

After that completes, you can review the ARP table with

```
arp -a
```

Kind of a "brute force" method, but it works using existing tools. This usually will resolve hosts that don't respond to ping, as well.

Answer (score 2):

From a bad, bad place, written by [scraig84](http://www.experts-exchange.com/M_660099.html):

> Typically you would need to find it on one of your machine's arp tables.  If there is a router in your network, this is usually the most central place to gather that type of info.  On a cisco router, the command is "show arp" - it will give you a listing of the MAC addresses and their corresponding IP address.  On a windows box, from a DOS prompt you can type "arp -a" to see similar output.